# Aggregating LSTM subsequence output into full sequence

Tags: machine-learning, lstm, speech-recognition, seq2seq

I have an `n->n` seq2seq LSTM that takes a sequence of length `n` and produces a sequence of length `n`. The sequences I am dealing with are audio signals. I am trying to use an LSTM to "de-noise" the audio.

So in a perfect world, for 1 second of audio at a sampling rate of 16000Hz, I would have an input sequence where `n=16000`, and then the LSTM would output the "de-noised" audio sequence of length `n=16000`. However, this takes far too long to train. Also, what if the audio is longer than 1 second?

So, it seems like the best thing to do would be train an LSTM on small chunks of 1 second of audio, say `n=800`. However, it is pointless if the LSTM de-noises the first 50ms, then the next 50ms etc. independently of each other. I could perhaps have some sliding window that extracts chunks that overlap with the previous chunk. But I am not sure how I would aggregate the outputs into a final 1 second audio clip...

How can I work around this long sequence problem? If I do break it down into subsequences, how do I tell the LSTM to retain information about the previous subsequence, or how do I aggregate the outputs of a sliding window?

Answer (score 0):

Tools like [segan](https://github.com/santi-pdp/segan_pytorch) split audio on 1 second chunks without overlap, denoise each separately and concatenate them together.

[RNNNoise](https://people.xiph.org/~jm/demo/rnnoise/) does overlap and add of 20ms windows with 50% overlap.

Comment: Interesting. Would you mind please elaborating a bit on what RNNNoise does? I had a read, but still don't quite understand.

Comment: Same as other packages, it cleans the noise based on very efficient neural networks. It applies some tricks in the middle - pitch estimation, etc. Not very fashionable but very compute efficient.

Comment: Overall, the longer is the audio chunk, the more reliably you can detect the noise. So for best denoiseing you need longer chunks.

Comment: Yep, I understand that. I just don’t understand how the RNNNoise aggregates outputs if it has overlapping windows.

Comment: What is the problem? You just overlap chunks and add them. It doesn't hurt much as you might think.

Comment: Say you input a 0.5s chunk and get 0.5s of cleaned audio as output, then do this for another 0.5s chunk with 50% overlap, you can’t just concatenation the two outputs because there is overlap.